# Which GitHub Fine grained access permissions are needed to upload a release to a different repository?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm managing a GitHub organisation, with multiple repositories running actions on release tags that generate a release for the repo.

I've started modifying the actions to upload the releases to a common Release repo to keep them all in one place, with the ncipollo/release-action github action, using a Basic token with the "repo" permission to upload.

I like to start using fine grained permissions instead but haven't been able to figure out the permissions needed. Have tried with:

- Read access to metadata
- Read and Write access to deployments
  but that fails.

Anyone know the correct permissions to use? Thanks.

nb. All repositories are private

Tried using the "Read and Write access to deployments" permission, but the upload fails.

Comment: Sorry, should have included the error:

"Error: Error 403: Resource not accessible by personal access token"

Token was issued by the organisation and owner (me). It was for the Release repository.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve by "*keep[ing] them all in one place*"? What kinds of artifacts do these releases consist of?

Comment: Installers and support files. We have multiple projects that generate their own releases, the Release repository brings them together in one spot for support and installation teams to access. That way I don't have to give non-devs access to code repositories and its convenient for the support team.

Comment: According to https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens?apiVersion=2022-11-28#contents, you need the `contents` write permission to create releases

Comment: Yup, just figured that out, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

And of course, I sorted out the issue shortly after posting...
The correct permission to use is "**Contents**" which covers "Repository contents, commits, branches, downloads, releases, and merges."